# Android: Releasing memory from finished activity does not work

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have an activity with some images and some buttons. When I click on one of the buttons I want to open the same activity with some other images. The thing is that when I start the new copy of the activity the memory from the previous activity doesn't released. On the OnClickListener for the buttons I tried both clearing memory cache and destroying the imageviews and also on the OnDestroy method but without result. I tried Volley, Picasso, Universal Image Loader and some other libraries for caching the images and still after some calls of the activities I get the OutOfMemory Exception. I see the MAT and on every call of the activity the previous stored bitmans on the heap are still there. Only when I press the back button it released. I also tried to update the current activity with the new images but still the leak remains and the old data are on memory. Any idea how to prevent the memory leak? I'm new and sorry if this question seems silly but I've been trying for 4 days to solve this without any result.

**Activity.java**

```
public void updateLayout(){
    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) act.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    sc.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);

    LinePageIndicator mIndicator = (LinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerImg);
    ImageProductAdapter adapter = new ImageProductAdapter(ProductActivity.this,item.getImageUrls(), item);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    mIndicator.getLayoutParams().height = mIndicator.getHeight() + 2;
    mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);


    if(!item.getRelatedItems().isEmpty()){

        GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.grid1);
        grid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        grid.removeAllViews();

        for(int i = 0; i < item.getRelatedItems().size(); i++) {
            final int j = i;
            ImageView v = new ImageView(this);
            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.no_image)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                    .build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(act.getApplicationContext()).build();
            com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
            com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader imageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();


            grid.addView(v);
            v.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
            v.getLayoutParams().width = 100;

            imageLoader.displayImage(item.getRelatedItems().get(i).getImageUrl(), v, options);

            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent activity = new Intent(ProductActivity.this,ProductActivity.class);
                    activity.putExtra("id", item.getRelatedItems().get(j).getProductID());
                    activity.putExtra("title", item.getRelatedItems().get(j).getTitle());
                    startActivity(activity);
                    act.finish();
                    }




            });
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` in your first `Activity` after you start a new instance of it with the new images?

Comment: Yes I call finish() on the previous.

Comment: Can you post your code? It sounds like you are keeping references to your activities in non-activity objects that prevent GC or some other issue that is not obvious from your description.

Comment: I update the original post.

Comment: Your ImageLoader class isn't acting as a singleton is it?

Comment: I use the default universal image loader. On volley which I tried to implement the some code I used a singleton and the exception remained.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that since the default behavior is for a new activity's back button to point to the activity it spawned from, that link is keeping all of your old activities alive in memory and safe from garbage collection. You need to remove that behavior, and then your old activities will be garbage collected properly.

This is why when you press the back button, the newest activity is released: nothing is referencing it.

First Activity ->(spawn new activity) ->Second activity -> (spawn new activity) -> third activity

The third activity's back button references the second, and the second's references the first. If you hit back on the third activity, its instance is garbage collected since nothing in the second activity links back to it.

As Squonk noted in the comments, you should call finish() before the next activity launches to clean away the activity and prevent this behavior.

Comment: I forgot to mention on it on first but I call finish everytime.

Comment: I also tried to update the current activity with the new informations rather than start a new and still the old data still remains on the heap.

Comment: What if you try overriding "public void onBackPressed()" 's default behavior?

Comment: Actually, can you post some of your code? That might help a lot